# How can I shorten header in a fasta file?

Tags: linux

I have a file that looks like this:

```
>Gene.10::S0008.1::g.10::m.10 Gene.10::S0008.1::g.10  ORF type:complete len:250 (-),score=22.42 S_0008.1:286-1035(-)
MKGDDFNIITAPVPINRIWWYSLTNRQRIALVFYMSFYVAGTLTNTASMFIDKFYIYIMR
LESLQMGSADPIDYKYLLEVQIVRGFWREDVHEVVDKVFRGKSIGYIKTNLMIPVEIWNN
CQVRSFRGIPCHSVAIICLIFGMLILYYHCTTVALFRTFMILNANLAAILLFIAMSMEYS
AAVEYDYCVNSVFMNRKTGGKAFVRGRYYNRTLEASGSTFKLMMVGDILFFCPMIGLGCY
LLFCNRENL* 
>Gene.11::S0009.1::g.10::m.11 Gene.11::S0009.1::g.10  ORF type:complete len:250 (-),score=22.42 S_0008.1:286-1035(-)
QSAISNDEELNKIMDA
....
```

I want to delete everything in the header after the first space. How can I do this easily in linux?

Resultant file:

```
>Gene.10::S0008.1::g.10::m.10 
MKGDDFNIITAPVPINRIWWYSLTNRQRIALVFYMSFYVAGTLTNTASMFIDKFYIYIMR
LESLQMGSADPIDYKYLLEVQIVRGFWREDVHEVVDKVFRGKSIGYIKTNLMIPVEIWNN
CQVRSFRGIPCHSVAIICLIFGMLILYYHCTTVALFRTFMILNANLAAILLFIAMSMEYS
AAVEYDYCVNSVFMNRKTGGKAFVRGRYYNRTLEASGSTFKLMMVGDILFFCPMIGLGCY
LLFCNRENL* 
>Gene.11::S0009.1::g.10::m.11 
QSAISNDEELNKIMDA
```

Comment: Technically, it's the second space, right?

Comment: You have a Python tag, but asked about Linux. Can you clarify which? Or are you asking about options for both?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use sed:

```
sed '/^>/s/^>\([^ ]*\) .*/>\1 /'
```

If a line starts with `>` then remove everything after the first space.  The following:

```
echo '>Gene.10::S0008.1::g.10::m.10 Gene.10::S0008.1::g.10  ORF type:complete len:250 (-),score=22.42 Sxl_rink_0008.1:286-1035(-)
MKGDDFNIITAPVPINRIWWYSLTNRQRIALVFYMSFYVAGTLTNTASMFIDKFYIYIMR
LESLQMGSADPIDYKYLLEVQIVRGFWREDVHEVVDKVFRGKSIGYIKTNLMIPVEIWNN
CQVRSFRGIPCHSVAIICLIFGMLILYYHCTTVALFRTFMILNANLAAILLFIAMSMEYS
AAVEYDYCVNSVFMNRKTGGKAFVRGRYYNRTLEASGSTFKLMMVGDILFFCPMIGLGCY
LLFCNRENL* 
>Gene.11::S0009.1::g.10::m.11 Gene.11::S0009.1::g.10  ORF type:complete len:250 (-),score=22.42 Sxl_rink_0008.1:286-1035(-)
QSAISNDEELNKIMDA' |  sed '/^>/s/^>\([^ ]*\) .*/>\1 /'
```

outputs:

```
>Gene.10::S0008.1::g.10::m.10 
MKGDDFNIITAPVPINRIWWYSLTNRQRIALVFYMSFYVAGTLTNTASMFIDKFYIYIMR
LESLQMGSADPIDYKYLLEVQIVRGFWREDVHEVVDKVFRGKSIGYIKTNLMIPVEIWNN
CQVRSFRGIPCHSVAIICLIFGMLILYYHCTTVALFRTFMILNANLAAILLFIAMSMEYS
AAVEYDYCVNSVFMNRKTGGKAFVRGRYYNRTLEASGSTFKLMMVGDILFFCPMIGLGCY
LLFCNRENL* 
>Gene.11::S0009.1::g.10::m.11 
QSAISNDEELNKIMDA
```

I don't know if the one space left after the header is relevant or not, but I left it.

If in those long lines of characters are no spaces anywhere, you can just remove everything until the first space with cut:

```
cut -d' ' -f1
```

which will remove all characters after the first space (including the space, dunno if the space is relevant).

@edit: As the OP edited both the input and the output, the answer now removes everything up to the first space, as to removing up to the second space...

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you will have a more readable solution :

```
awk 'NR==1{print $1}NR!=1{print}' test.txt
```

Then you can redirect output to new file to store the fix :

```
 awk 'NR==1{print $1}NR!=1{print}' test.txt > new_test.txt
```

**EDIT**

I thought there was multiple files, and just one header per file.

```
awk '{print $1}' test.txt
```

would work on your example as other lines does not contain spaces

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/ .*// if /^>/' -- file.fasta
```